# Asterisk in the definition of a struct

Tags: c

What does the asterisk (*) do in the end of the struct definition?
Is this the definition to a pointer of a unnamed struct?

riscv.c (from openOCD-Project: [src/target/riscv/riscv.c:195](http://www.openocd.org/doc/doxygen/html/riscv_8c_source.html))

```
struct {
    uint16_t low, high;
} *expose_csr;
```

Comment: "Is this the definition to a pointer of a unnamed struct?" Yes.

Comment: why would I use such a construct? Is it a struct I don't care of. Or something like a single union to interpret a ```unt32_t``` or something? One thing I got, it's a handy way to define a pointer pointing to something more complex!?

Comment: You often have this kind of thing in the embedded world. The documentation of your piece of hardware says that it will write 32 bits to this or that place, and that the first 16 bit are the low value and the other 16 bit are the high value in unsigned representation. Then with a `struct` definition like this you can make `expose_csr` point to those 32 bits and read from / write to those values with `expose_csr.low` and `expose_csr.high`.

Comment: If you continue to read the source, it seems to be about ranges of values.

Comment: you've helped me out! thx

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to not give a struct definition a 'tag' name, because most debuggers use the 'tag' name to access the individual fields within the struct

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a definition of a pointer to an unnamed structure. This can be quite useful for structures that are only ever referenced through that pointer, since it makes it impossible to create an instance statically for instance.